# Django database design - Use an attribute or a method

Tags: django, django-models

I have what I thought was a simple question. I am designing a database and I have a doubt about it.

this is the model

```
class DailyCash(models.Model):
    # Relations
    # Attributes - Mandatory
    initial_cash = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=10,
        decimal_places=2,
        verbose_name=_('initial cash'),
    )
    daily_incomes = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=10,
        decimal_places=2,
        verbose_name=_('daily incomes'),
    )
    daily_expenses = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=10,
        decimal_places=2,
        verbose_name=_('daily expenses'),
    )
    next_initial_cash = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=10,
        decimal_places=2,
        verbose_name=_('next initial cash'),
    )
    # Attributes - Optional
    # Object Manager
    objects = managers.DailyCashManager()
    # Custom Properties
    # Methods

    # Meta and String
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("Daily Cash")
        verbose_name_plural = _("Daily Cash")
        ordering = ('id')

    def __str__(self):
        pass
```

Well, my dobut is I need to calculate the daily balance but I'm not sure if is better use a attribute for this value or use a property what is fastest for future uses when the daily cash have more than 3 years or something like that to make the monthly balances or year or what i need, what is better for this in a future.

use a field daily_balance and store in the database the value or calculate this value each time it's needed

like this

```
@property
def daily_balance(self):
    return self.initial_cash + self.daily_incomes - self.daily_expenses - self.next_initial_cash
```

Well, thats my doubt use a property (method) or store that value direct in the database.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are doing right.

Don't need to store the value of the balance.
And if you need, you could do it. As easy as execute a simple routine to fill up a new field.

I don't think you will gain speed storing the value, because a well done query is fast, see for this case aggregation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/aggregation/